# Демон заснул и не просыпается

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, администрирование, демон

У меня есть шел скрипт который я сохранил в `/etc/init.d/my_service` примерно следующего содержания

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo -u www-data php -f /var/www/my_service.php > /var/log/my_service.log 2>&1 &
```

Запускаю PHP скрипт как демон от имени пользователя www-data и весь вывод сохраняю в лог файл

PHP скрипт имеет общий вид (используется Symfony и Doctrine)

```
<?php
while (true) {
   // получаем запись из БД
   $entity = $this->repository->findEntity();

    if ($entity) {
        $this->handler->handleEntity($entity); // что-то делаем
        $this->em->flush(); // сохраняем изменение в бд

        // бросаем событие об успешном выполнении действия
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(StoreEvents::UPDATE_ENTITY, new UpdateEntity($entity));
    }

    $sleep = rand(10, 800);
    echo "sleep $sleep s.\n";
    sleep($sleep); // засыпаем
    unset($entity); // удаляем неиспользуемый объект
    gc_collect_cycles(); // garbage collection
}
```

так вот. Проблема заключается в том что скрипт работает несколько дней, а потом зависает. В логах я вижу что последнее его действие было `sleep 10 s.`. Действия которые должен выполнять этот скрипт, он не выполняет, но при этом он работает. Не упал.

```
$ ps aux | grep my_service | grep -v grep
root     14517  0.0  0.1  54092  3856 ?        S    июн17   0:00 sudo -u www-data php -f /var/www/my_service.php
www-data 14518  0.1  7.4 496776 151844 ?       S    июн17   5:15 php -f /var/www/my_service.php
```

В error логах пусто. Утечек память за скриптом я не наблюдаю. За 4 дня скрипт съел 7.4% памяти (это в пределах нормы). А вот мускул съел 47%, но там база несколько гигов, так что тоже норм. На диске место есть. Память свободная еще есть.

В общем вопрос. Что я делаю не так и куда копать? Вопрос скорей по диагностике ошибке.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ uname -r
4.4.0-22-generic

$ php -v
PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.12, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

PS: Отказаться от PHP не представляется возможным в силу сложной бизнес логики завязанной на сайт.

Вывод gdb. Возможно это кому-то что-то скажет

```
$ gdb -pid=14518
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f7dd8bb8d13 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0x00007f7dd4920f59 in zif_curl_multi_select () from /usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so
#2  0x000055d4b6f138aa in dtrace_execute_internal ()
#3  0x000055d4b6fa7320 in ?? ()
#4  0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#5  0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#6  0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#7  0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#8  0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#9  0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#10 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#11 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#12 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#13 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#14 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#15 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#16 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#17 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#18 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#19 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#20 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#21 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#22 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#23 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#24 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#25 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#26 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#27 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#28 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#29 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#30 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#31 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#32 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#33 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#34 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#35 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#36 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#37 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#38 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#39 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#40 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#41 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#42 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#43 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#44 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#45 0x000055d4b6fa745d in ?? ()
#46 0x000055d4b6f6316b in execute_ex ()
#47 0x000055d4b6f13741 in dtrace_execute_ex ()
#48 0x000055d4b6fb5fd7 in zend_execute ()
#49 0x000055d4b6f23993 in zend_execute_scripts ()
#50 0x000055d4b6ec44e0 in php_execute_script ()
#51 0x000055d4b6fb7ca4 in ?? ()
#52 0x000055d4b6da9d54 in main ()
```

еще несколько отладочных выводов

```
# ps -flp 14518
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S www-data 14518 14517  0  80   0 - 124194 poll_s июн17 ?    00:05:21 php /var/www/my_service.php

# cat /proc/14518/wchan
poll_schedule_timeout

# cat /proc/14518/status
Name:   php
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   14518
Ngid:   0
Pid:    14518
PPid:   14517
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    33      33      33      33
Gid:    33      33      33      33
FDSize: 64
Groups: 33
NStgid: 14518
NSpid:  14518
NSpgid: 14511
NSsid:  14410
VmPeak:   496776 kB
VmSize:   496776 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:    153076 kB
VmRSS:    143508 kB
VmData:   202320 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:      3744 kB
VmLib:     60980 kB
VmPTE:       776 kB
VmPMD:        16 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
HugetlbPages:          0 kB
Threads:        1
SigQ:   0/7851
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000001006
SigCgt: 0000000184000000
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
Seccomp:        0
Cpus_allowed:   1
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:      0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:        277710
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     45436

# cat /proc/14518/sched
php (14518, #threads: 1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
se.exec_start                                :    1019977529.238328
se.vruntime                                  :       4031586.862977
se.sum_exec_runtime                          :        321340.158466
se.statistics.sum_sleep_runtime              :     346194990.429695
se.statistics.wait_start                     :             0.000000
se.statistics.sleep_start                    :    1019977529.238328
se.statistics.block_start                    :             0.000000
se.statistics.sleep_max                      :        882000.078842
se.statistics.block_max                      :             3.172846
se.statistics.exec_max                       :            12.163842
se.statistics.slice_max                      :            55.799938
se.statistics.wait_max                       :             8.977077
se.statistics.wait_sum                       :         13045.256734
se.statistics.wait_count                     :               323374
se.statistics.iowait_sum                     :            77.360204
se.statistics.iowait_count                   :                  138
se.nr_migrations                             :                    0
se.statistics.nr_migrations_cold             :                    0
se.statistics.nr_failed_migrations_affine    :                    0
se.statistics.nr_failed_migrations_running   :                    0
se.statistics.nr_failed_migrations_hot       :                    0
se.statistics.nr_forced_migrations           :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups                     :               277937
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_sync                :                38357
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_migrate             :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_local               :               277937
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_remote              :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_affine              :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_affine_attempts     :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_passive             :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_idle                :                    0
avg_atom                                     :             0.993710
avg_per_cpu                                  :             0.000001
nr_switches                                  :               323374
nr_voluntary_switches                        :               277938
nr_involuntary_switches                      :                45436
se.load.weight                               :                 1024
se.avg.load_sum                              :                88064
se.avg.util_sum                              :                88064
se.avg.load_avg                              :                    0
se.avg.util_avg                              :                    0
se.avg.last_update_time                      :     1019977529238328
policy                                       :                    0
prio                                         :                  120
clock-delta                                  :                  153
mm->numa_scan_seq                            :                    0
numa_pages_migrated                          :                    0
numa_preferred_nid                           :                   -1
total_numa_faults                            :                    0
current_node=0, numa_group_id=0
numa_faults node=0 task_private=0 task_shared=0 group_private=0 group_shared=0

# cat /proc/14518/schedstat
321346945436 13045546406 323441

# cat /proc/14518/syscall
23 0xe 0x7ffcf3aa6110 0x7ffcf3aa6190 0x7ffcf3aa6210 0x7ffcf3aa6100 0x0 0x7ffcf3aa60d0 0x7f7dd8bb8d13

# cat /proc/14518/stack
[<ffffffff81220dc4>] poll_schedule_timeout+0x44/0x70
[<ffffffff812218b7>] do_select+0x727/0x810
[<ffffffff81221b6f>] core_sys_select+0x1cf/0x2f0
[<ffffffff81221d4a>] SyS_select+0xba/0x110
[<ffffffff818252f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

fd

```
# ls -la /proc/14518/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 www-data www-data  0 Jun 21 15:31 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 www-data www-data  0 Jun 17 16:41 ..
lr-x------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 1 -> /var/www/my_service.log
lrwx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 10 -> socket:[276448] # <====== прокси для php
lrwx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 11 -> socket:[275207] # <====== прокси для php
l-wx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 12 -> /var/www/my_service/failed_load.log # <====== дополнительный внутренний лог
lrwx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 13 -> socket:[276877] # <====== прокси для php
l-wx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 2 -> /var/www/my_service.log
lr-x------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 3 -> /dev/urandom
l-wx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 4 -> /var/www/my_service.log
l-wx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 5 -> /var/www/my_service.log
lrwx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 6 -> socket:[245767] # <====== дескриптор не найден
l-wx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 7 -> /var/www/my_service/dev.log # <====== дополнительный внутренний лог
lrwx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 8 -> socket:[276838] # <====== прокси для php
lrwx------ 1 www-data www-data 64 Jun 21 15:31 9 -> socket:[245781] # <====== прокси для php
```

ошибся. последнее действие было не sleep (обнаружил в другом логе)

```
[2016-06-19 00:10:33] app.DEBUG: Sleep: 141 s. [] []
[2016-06-19 00:12:54] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT ...
```

последняя запись из лога в который записывается весь вывод программы `> /var/log/my_service.log 2>&1`

```
[2016-06-19 00:10:33] app.DEBUG: Sleep: 141 s.
```

gdb

```
# gdb /proc/14518/exe
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11-0ubuntu1) 7.11
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /proc/14518/exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) attach 14518
Attaching to program: /proc/14518/exe, process 14518
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so...done.
done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so...done.
done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so...done.
done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so...done.
done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/b7/7847cc9cacbca3b5753d0d25a32e5795afe75b.debug...done.
done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...warning: the debug information found in "/lib64/ld-2.23.so" does not match "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" (CRC mismatch).

Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so...done.
done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/opcache.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqlnd.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/xml.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/apcu.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so...done.
done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/calendar.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/ctype.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so...done.
done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/dom.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/exif.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/fileinfo.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/ftp.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgd.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/gettext.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/iconv.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/intl.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuio.so.55...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/json.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/memcached.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmemcached.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/phar.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/posix.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/readline.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/shmop.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/simplexml.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/sockets.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/sysvmsg.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/sysvsem.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/sysvshm.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/tidy.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libtidy-0.99.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/tokenizer.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/wddx.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlreader.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlwriter.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexslt.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so...done.
done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.23.so...done.
done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so...done.
done.
0x00007f7dd8bb8d13 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

все файловые дескрипторы к сокету `socket:[xxx]` кроме *245767* выполняли роль прокси для curl запросов из php. дескриптор 245767 не найден

```
# netstat -apeen | grep 245767
```

возможно на дескриптор 245767 находился мускул. он отвалился как-то, а скрипт не смог среагировать на это. в логе вижу только это сообщение, но оно было через 5 часов после остановки скрипта.

```
2016-06-19T05:12:54.819918Z 179 [Note] Aborted connection 179 to db: 'database' user: 'user' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
```

версия курла

```
# curl -V
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

демон умер

```
[2016-06-19 00:10:33] app.DEBUG: Sleep: 141 s.
[2016-06-21 23:38:12] php.DEBUG: PDO::beginTransaction(): send of 22 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe {"type":8,"file":"/var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php","line":1176,"level":28928}


[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=14518
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41485/discussion-on-question-by-ghost404-----).

Comment: я бы не стал класть такое в /etc/init.d/ так как он будет запускаться и виснуть при любом действии с сервисами и при остановке тоже.

сделайте юнит для системд или апстарт лучше - пара строчек конфига, а зато можно им нормально управлять.

если всетаки систем-V то `start-stop-deamon` крутейшая штука

Comment: сделал форк процесса и в дочернем уже выполнял все необходимые действия. полет нормальный. правда возникла новая проблема. на каком-то этапе работы доктрина начала бросать исключения, потому что не удалось записать данные в бд, и в этом случае дочерний процесс зависал и не умирал сам. но эта проблема уже из другой серии

Answer (score 3):

Запускайте скрипт через крон, например каждые две минуты, выполняйте нужное количество итераций и выходите.

P.S. Это не демон. Демон - слушает, создает коннекты и т.д. Он злой и многопоточный. У вас просто скрипт, который раз в 10 секунд должен обработать пачку данных из БД. Не переусложняйте.

`unset($entity); // удаляем неиспользуемый объект` зачем unset, если он в следующей итерации будет перезаписан?

Если вы хотите написать статью на хабр как дебажить PHP/Симфони/Доктрину -  сейчас вы на правильном пути. Могу посоветовать вам инструменты вроде http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html для профайлинга дампов PHP. Поскольку дамп за несколько дней займет слишком много места, вы можете написать скрипт, который проверяет отзывчивость сервера, если сервер отзывается, скрипт сбрасывает все дампы старше пяти минут. если не отзывается, скрипт прекращает процесс дампа.

В итоге вы  сможете посмотреть все вызовы функций за пять минут до зависания сервера.  Для ускорения процесса, можете снизить таймаут в скрипте до одной секунды - при запуске на тестовом сервере.

Если хотите выполнить бизнес-задачу - не надо переусложнять. Используйте крон.

Comment: "подопри костылем"

Comment: это не костыль а вполне стандартная практика в больших конторах. php только недавно начали использовать в виде долгоживущих процессах. если вам нужно запустить скрипт, чтобы он корректно отработал, вы не будете дебажить миллион библиотек и расширений php, вы просто исключите возможность утечек памяти и т.д. Тем более, это не демон, а просто скрипт в итерации.

Comment: В плохих больших конторах. В виде долгоживущих процессов далеко не первый год запускают, и далеко не всегда есть возможность запускать в формате one-off. Ну и закрывать глаза на проблемы кода можно, но не нужно.

Comment: в хороших больших конторах тяжелых демонов пишут на других языках, а этот код, в любом случае, вполне кандидат для обычного запуска через крон.

Comment: @strangeqargo `unset($entity);` да, при следующем вызове переменная затрется, но если ее явно не освободить, то ссылка на объект может сохранится в памяти и `gc_collect_cycles();` не удалит ее. Как результат утечка памяти. Сталкивался с такой проблемой несколько лет назад. Как сейчас не проверял.

Comment: @strangeqargo `Запускайте скрипт через крон` крон мне не подходит потому что интервал между итерациями рандомный. не описал это в задаче. извиняюсь

Comment: @strangeqargo на самом деле это демон который выполняет какие-то задачи по своему собственному расписанию. Рандомному расписанию. Если сделать выполнение задач через fork то это точно будет уже демон, а не обычный, неумирающий скрипт

Comment: @ghost404 да вам без разницы, рэндомный он или нет, запускается, проверяет условия/рэндом, выполняет задачу или крутит итерации, гарантированно умирает. Запускается снова. В любом случае, удачи вам.

Comment: @strangeqargo спасибо. Попробую пройтись профайлером. Но скорей всего буду делать как рекомендует jekaby. По крону проверять работу демона и перезапускать при зависании

Comment: @ghost404 кастыль же, зачем использовать крон для проверки какого то скрипта когда можно просто крон для запуска использовать

Comment: @Naumov окей. и с каким интервалом я должен его запускать? у меня разброс 10-800 секунд. скрипт за 800 секунд может отработать 1 раз, а может и 80. причем верхняя планка для ренда меняется в зависимости от ряда условий. получается я должен убивать скрипт через 800 с работы, а в кроне каждые 800 с. перезапускать его. И все условия для определения верхней планки я должен как-то переносить в крон. Вот это точно усложнение задачи

Comment: @ghost404 дак всё просто, разброс из за чего? из за того что вы хотите што бы были выполнены какие то операции и после этих операций запускался скрипт снова. Для этого просто при запуске проверяем есть ли фаил блокировки, если нет идём дальше и создаём его, после выполнения удаляем фаил. так по крону запускаете.

Comment: @Naumov то-есть каждую секунду кроном дергать скрипт или файл блокировки? И как это поможет от засыпания скрипта? Все равно по таймауту через крон я должен убивать файл блокировки, заснувший процесс и перезапускать скрипт

Comment: @Naumov давайте так. юзкейс. нужно выполнить команду/программу в бесконечном цыкле (много раз пока не надоест) и с случайным интервалом запуска (интервал между выполнением команд от 10 до 800 секунд). И должна быть возможность отлавливать зависание как выполняемой команды, так и управляющего скрипта. Какое решение вы можете предложить? Может я чего-то не знаю. Когда я работал в соцсети у нас управляющий скрипт тупо перезапускали из крона, а он в свою очередь, запускал/перезапуска другие процессы которые что-то делали. Но там не было никакого рандома. Это был просто управляющий процесс.

Answer (score 0):

Надежнее использовать обертку на bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    /usr/local/bin/php -f /var/www/my_service.php
    sleep 60
done;
```

Так точно будут освобождаться ресурсы после каждого запуска скрипта.